# Database schema design for large number of columns

Tags: oracle, database-design

I have a use case where I need to model reference data for e.g. different flavors of ice cream. Say I have 50 flavors of ice cream :-

- 20 attributes e.g. freezing-temp, creaminess will be shared across all flavors
- every flavor of ice cream would have 20-30 attributes that will not be shared with other flavors e.g. :-

  - Strawberry ice cream might track tartness, fruit percentage etc.
  - Chocolate ice cream might track bitterness, cocoa level etc.

How would I model this data neatly in a database model, purely from a storage / retrieval point of view?

The options I can think of :-

1. One table per flavor. This will need 50 tables, and each table will have 20 columns that will overlap with each other, and another 20-30 attributes that will be unique to the flavor.

   - Pros : models the data of each flavor quite well
   - Cons : column overlap and large number of tables needed
2. One table for all flavors. This will only need 1 table, but will require 1000+ columns most of which would be empty.

   - Pros : models the data of ice cream in general, quite well
   - Cons : large number of columns and large amount of 'wasted' space
3. One key-value table for all flavors, with flavor Id, attribute name and attribute value.

   - Pros : simplest to create and insert data
   - Cons : harder to extract, not really a data model per se, difficult to form constraints for attributes, or for attributes related to other attributes

Comment: Probably a better fit on [dba.se]

Comment: In my long-if-not-particularly-distinguished career I have *never* had a DBA do database design work. IMO this is valid on StackOverflow.

Comment: thank you! most if not all of our db design is done by developers too ...

Comment: There is such a thing as a development DBA.  The term "database architect" might be more apropos than "database administrator".  Such a person has to be able to think in ways that would be a disaster in a production DBA.  Think prototyping and rapid revision cycles, instead of stability and reliability.

Comment: Don't have developers develop databases if they have never had experience with databases in the real world, however.  You can't afford to learn from your own mistakes here.  You have to learn from the mistakes of others.  Unless, of course, your database is just a phat phile.

Answer (score 1):

**Never store a value in the wrong type.**

[image]

Whatever design you choose, make sure that values are stored in their natural format.  Use NUMBER, DATE, VARCHAR2, CLOB, XMLTYPE, CLOB (IS JSON), TIMESTAMP, etc.  Trying to cram everything in a string will cause many problems.  You lose validation, convenience, performance, and type safety.

For example, here is a common type safety problem.  Imagine this simple query to find ice cream that is more than 25% fruit:

```
select *
from   ice_cream_flavor_attribute
where  attribute_name = 'Fruit Percentage'
   and attribute_value > 25;
```

Do you see the bug?  Do you see how the same query, with the same data, may work one day and fail the next with `ORA-01722: invalid number`?

It's difficult to write a query that forces Oracle to evaluate conditions in a specific order.  Re-ordering the predicates won't help (99.9% of the time).  Adding an inline view won't help (99.9% of the time).  Using a `CASE` statement will work but not 100% of the time.  Using hints will work but is tricky.  Using an inline view and a `ROWNUM` is my preferred way of solving the problem but it looks odd and is difficult to understand.

---

If you must use an Entity Attribute Value model (and if you have more than 1000 attributes it may be unavoidable), at least use the right types.

Don't worry about space - a null column uses at most 1 byte.

Don't worry about complaints like "but then our queries are more complicated, we always need to know which column to use!" - realistically there is almost nothing useful you can do with a value without knowing its type.  Every time you read or write a value you must already be thinking about the type.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have one table with all the common attributes, then another for the non-shared attributes. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE ICE_CREAM_FLAVOR
  (FLAVOR          VARCHAR2(100) PRIMARY KEY,
   FREEZING_TEMP   NUMBER,
   CREAMINESS      NUMBER,
   ETC             VARCHAR2(25),
   BLAH            NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE ICE_CREAM_FLAVOR_ATTRIBUTE
  (ID_ICF_ATTRIBUTE  NUMBER,  -- should be populated by an insert trigger
   FLAVOR            VARCHAR2(100)
     NOT NULL
     REFERENCES ICE_CREAM_FLAVOR(FLAVOR),
   ATTRIBUTE_NAME    VARCHAR2(25),
   ATTRIBUTE_VALUE   VARCHAR2(100));
```

Your mileage may vary.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: thanks - we thought about this as well and wonder if it's worth using two different 'styles' to capture the information. If say we encapsulate the difference using a db view or server side processing, different approach would be needed if let's say we expose it on a GUI for editing. How the data needs to be saved would be different (might cause us hibernate headaches)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest, You can create 3 different tables.

1. Ice Cream Flavor: You can store all the flavors of ice cream. It will be icecream_flavor_master table. Let say if you have 50 flavors than 50 rows will create,  like Strawberry,Chocolate etc.
2. Ice Cream Attributes: You can store all the attributes of ice cream. It will icecream_attribute_master table. Let say if you have 50 attributes than 50 rows will create, like tartness,bitterness,fruit percentage, cocoa level etc.
3. Ice Cream Flavor Attributes: You can store primary key of icecream_flavor_master and icecream_attribute_master in this table, to make the relation between flavor and attribute of icecream.

Let me know for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to group flavors into classes of flavors, ones that share certain attributes.  This lends itself to classes and subclasses that extend other classes.

If you want to do ER modeling on this, look up "generalization/specialization" on the web.  Some websites will call this a feature of "Extended ER modeling" or EER.

If you want to design relational tables to implement the ER design, look into two patterns:  Single Table Inheritance and Class Table Inheritance.
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/single-table-inheritance/info

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/class-table-inheritance/info

Also, look into Martin Fowler's treatment on this subject on the web, or in one of his textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

What big vendors are doing for huge data in ECM (enterprise content management), where you have a quite similar scenario (many custom classes with custom attributes, some of them might be the same, having various types over attributes):

3. One key-value table for all flavors, with flavor Id, attribute name and attribute value.

They use one key-value table per type (string, number, date etc.).

For performance optimization, they allow to define dedicated tables for attributes, in order to keep index small and not crowded with other attributes.

Dedicated tables make sense for:

- Massive usage (having many rows)
- Bad histograms (like flags)

Otherwise Oracle index could be tricked, and full table access is the fastest access, which would be really bad.
So think early about performance when having huge amount of data.